# Disabling Apache Derby's Caches

Tags: performance, caching, derby

I need to do some performance testing with a Derby DB. I want to do several test runs, however, all but the first run take only very few milliseconds. I assume, that Derby some (query result) caches which serves all queries after the first one.

Of course, this is not what I want. I want Derby to execute the statements again and again and not to cache the query results.

How can I disable all caching within Derby to get proper performance test results?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Derby doesn't cache the query results. It caches the statement execution plan; it caches some pages from the database tables; but it doesn't cache the query results.

I don't know why you would think that disabling all caching in Derby is necessary in order to get proper performance results.